# Text to Column with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to create a code to seperate text to columns: Therefore I used the recording function VBA. But it showed me everytime an error '1004'.

```
Sub Makro6()

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
        "_", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), _
        Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error message? Make sure `Selection` is a proper range and not a chart or other object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is written as `Selection.TextToColumns` meaning the user must select the cell containing the text before running the macro. If the selected cell is blank then you will encounter the error 1004 that you are getting. To avoid this issue, I suggest you put in a specific range instead of using the Selected cell as the input.

I suggest changing `Selection.TextToColumns` to `Range("YourNamedRange").TextToColumns` where "YourNamedRange" is something like "A1" and making sure the input text always goes into the same cell.